# Javascript running "out of order"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I am attempting to do a simple user signup, but am having trouble getting the proper checks for creating duplicate user's to run in the sequence I am intending:

route:

```
app.post('/user/new', user.create);
```

user.create:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
var exists = DoesUserExist(req, res);
console.log(exists);
if (exists === true){
    console.log("exists");
    res.redirect('/user/new');
}
else{
    //good to create user since it does not exist yet
    CreateUser(req, res);
    console.log("does not");
    res.redirect('/user/new');
}
 };
```

helper funcs:

```
function DoesUserExist(req, res){
var post = req.body;

mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db", function(err, db){
    if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

    var collection = db.collection("users");
    collection.find({username: post.username}).count( function( err, count ){
        if (count > 0){
            console.log(count);
            return true; //already exists
        }
        else{
            console.log(count);
            return false; //does not exist
        }
    });
});
}


function CreateUser(req, res){
var post = req.body;

//connect to db server
mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", function(err, db){
    if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

    var collection = db.collection("users");
    collection.insert({username: post.username, password : post.password}, function(error, doc){});
});

return;
}
```

after running the program again to see if I can add a duplicate username, my console logs return:

```
undefined
does not
POST /user/new 302 4ms - 74b
1
```

and my mongodb shows a duplicate record. The flow of the program is not adhering to what I perceive it to be. Am I failing to use a callback appropriately in this case? I am still new to javascript and would like some pointers/critiques. Thanks.

Comment: As far as pointers go: a) instead of `if (x === true)`, just write `if (x)`;  b) don’t capitalize the first letters of function names unless they’re constructors. Your `if (count > 0) { console.log(count); return true; } else { console.log(count); return false; }` could also just be `console.log(count); return count > 0;` – but does it do anything in the first place? You should also be handling the error case in every callback. `return;` at the end of a function is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on callbacks, because node programming is all about callbacks.

When you call `DoesUserExist()`, it calls `mongo.connect()` and **immediately returns**. (You can put "console.log('hi')" at the end of `DoesUserExist()` to verify it's called before your "if count > 0" code.) The `Mongo.connect()` routine takes a callback, so it is not a simple synchronous function. It calls that function (as a callback) *only when the results of the query are ready.* Therefore, the "return" isn't returning from `DoesUserExist`, but from your anonymous function passed to the mongo driver.

Instead of "return true/false", you need to call you "res.redirect" logic. You can do this by taking the "if/then" code in `user.create` and turn it into an anonymous function. Pass that to `DoesUserExist()`, which will call it in the "count" callback.

When the "count" callback runs and calls your anonymous function, it will have: 1) the value of count, and 2) the `req/res` object to do the redirect on.

I could write the code for you, but it's really something you need to play with and read up on until you get the "aha" moment to understand all callbacks.

Comment: thanks for the info. Do you have any suggested reading to get me up to speed with js callbacks?

Comment: There are a lot. Just search for node and callbacks and keep reading until you get it. https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks